# Search by reference field target ID

Tags: 8, entities, search

I have a *Project* content type, which has a reference field to a *Contact* entity that has a *Client* bundle.

I can get the reference target ID from the node. I want to find the nodes that contain a reference to *Client* entities.

How should I be able to search in the node reference field target IDs to find the similar?

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing a completely unrelated and already answered question.

Comment: @leymannx I don't have permission, my account limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.6.x) to search for referenced entities.

Let’s illustrate a couple of examples of querying for node entities using this object.

A very simple query that returns the published nodes:

```
function ecc_general_node_update(Node $node) {
    // Find the project for current client that are actives
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('type','project')
      ->condition('field_project_status', 'Active')
      ->condition('field_client', $node->field_client->target_id);
    $searchNodes = $query->execute();
    var_dump($searchNodes);
}
```

The out put looks like this, just the nodes IDs appears:

> array (size=2)
>
> 106 => string '101' (length=3)
>
> 109 => string '104' (length=3)

Answer (score 1):

This is often achieved using Views with a Contextual filter that pulls in the current node ID and uses it as the "parent" to find the "children" of that Entity Reference field.

Here is a similar question/answer with all the steps how to set it up:
List "ER Child" info on "ER Parent" nodes
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/280876/52224

Using Views is often the more maintainable solution. Using custom queries is sometimes used when Views query performance isn't good enough and needs to be optimized.